# Get horizontal scroll event in js

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos, dom-events

What I want to do, is to catch the event when the user is scrolling div horizontally.
For vertical scroll I am using event 'mousewheel' and it's working properly. ( horizontal scroll is performed by a two finger drag on the touchpad - I am testing on Mac OS).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can handle horizontal scrolling by :

```
$("#someContainer").on("scroll", function (e) {
            horizontal = e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
            vertical = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
            });
```

In this case this bind all kind of scroll events on this element so you can also handle

Vertical by `e.currentTarget.scrollTop`

and

Horizontal by `e.currentTarget.scrollLeft`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the proper setup to test this, but [`$.scroll()`](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) should do the trick. It's probably preferable to binding the `mousewheel` event as well. People use all means of scrolling ;)