# Detect Left Scroll JavaScript

Tags: javascript

What code would I add to trigger a block of code when the div is being scrolled left?

```
<script>
(function () {
    function scrollH(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollH, false);
        window.addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollH, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollH);
    }
    if "scrollingLeft" {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something else
    }
})();
</script>
```

So far I have tried the following to no avail:

```
var isleft = e.delta < 0;
if isleft = true { do something }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This solution will detect the DOM event. The div doesn't need to have some scrolling bars

You should be able to detect the scroll direction with this snippet :

```
$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll mousewheel', function (e) {
  if(e.originalEvent.detail > 0 || e.originalEvent.wheelDeltaX < 0) { //alternative options for wheelData: wheelDeltaX & wheelDeltaY
    //scroll right
    console.log("RIGHT");
  } else {
    //scroll left
    console.log("LEFT");
  }

  //prevent page fom scrolling
  return false;
});
```

It should work with all browsers. If you need to detect horizontal direction, replace `wheelDeltaX`with `wheelDeltaY`

If you want to detect the scroll direction and let the page scroll, `return true`at the end

Answer (score 2):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13233272/2649739)
You can handle horizontal scrolling by :

```
$("#someContainer").on("scroll", function (e) {
    horizontal = e.currentTarget.scrollLeft;
    vertical = e.currentTarget.scrollTop;
});
```

In this case this bind all kind of scroll events on this element so you can also handle

Vertical by `e.currentTarget.scrollTop`

and

Horizontal by `e.currentTarget.scrollLeft`

Comment: It should also work, but only if the page is really scrolling