# Detect 'manual' horizontal scroll on div

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to detect `manual` horizontal scroll on a div. If I add an event listener to a div I want to be able to differentiate between a user manually scrolling with the mouse vs when the div gets larger when something expands. I could add a flag on every action that could potentially grow the div and trigger the event but there has to be a better way.

Here's some code to mess around with

```js
function enlarge() {
    document.querySelector('.inner').style.width = '400px';
}
```

```css
div {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.inner {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>

<button onclick="enlarge()">
enlarge
</button>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get horizontal scroll event in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233149/get-horizontal-scroll-event-in-js)

Comment: Changing the size of the inner div doesn't scroll the main one. You can just attach a `scroll` event listener to the main div.